# PyQt5 и MySQL. Driver not loaded

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, gui, qtsql

Изучаю *PyQt5* и *MySQL*. При попытке соединения с базой данных *MySQL* получаю сообщение:"**`Driver not loaded`**".

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#Открываем БД MySQL
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setPort(3306)
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("mydb")
db.setUserName("root")
db.setPassword("*******")
db.open()
print(db.lastError().text())
print(db.drivers())
db.close()
```

Output:

```
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Система:

```
Windows 7 64x, Python 3.8.3, PyQt5 v5.15.4
```

Что было сделано:

1. Прописал в PATH:

> C:\MySQL\bin;
> C:\MySQL\lib;
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers;
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\sqldrivers;
>
> C:\Users\cash\PycharmProjects\QtProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\sqldrivers;

2. Добавил в папку с проектом `ibmysql.dll`, `libmysql.lib`, `mysqlclient.lib`.
3. Пробовал добавлять в папку:

> ```
> C:\Users\cash\PycharmProjects\QtProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\sqldrivers;
> ```

файл `qsqlmysql.dll`, тогда код работает но вывод следующий:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Если же убрать *QMYSQL* в строке

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("")
```

То вывод

```
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Если *QMSQL* поменять на *QSQLITE* всё работает, но мне нужно, что бы *PyQt5* соединялся с *MySQL*. 
Заранее благодарю сообщество за помощь.

Comment: Я не могу проверить ваш пример сейчас, но предложу вам 
скопируйте файл `libmysql.dll` в каталог `.../Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/bin` 

Я не думаю что вам нужна строка - `db.setPort(3306)`

Comment: Воспользовался вашим советом, пока что никаких изменений.